# Prevent sorting jquery datatable- server side processing

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jquery data table with server side process. i dont want to use sort by column feature of it so i have not done anything for sorting at server. it works well but the problem is whenever i click any header of column it fire event and send request to server. i dont want this to be happen. how can i stop that event..

jquery:

```
  var table= $('#datatable').DataTable({
             columns: [
                 { 'data': 'Id' },
                 { 'data': 'Name' },
                 { 'data': 'Address' }   
             ],
             bServerSide: true,
             sAjaxSource: '/Test/Student.asmx/Get',
             sServerMethod: 'post'
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in datatable js function..

```
var oTable_Data = $('#id').dataTable(
    {
       "language": {
                     "sSearch": '',
                     "searchPlaceholder": "Search"
                   },
       "aaSorting": [],
       "bPaginate":true,
       "bLengthChange": false,
       "bFilter":true,
       "bDestroy":true,
       "bInfo": false,
       "aoColumns":[{"bSortable": false}]
    });
```

**"aaSorting": [ ]** will disable automatic sorting..

**"aoColumns":[{"bSortable": false}]** will remove sorting.

Comment: Try to rectify the problem. you answer is right but not in this perspective, you are just answering how to handle the sorting issue but question is different.